# Razorpay recurring payment through token

Tags: php, laravel, token, payment, razorpay

I am trying to make a recurring payment through charge token.I want to implement this by API.
I am using the below code make fist payment and save token this is working fine.

```
 <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
                data-key="RAZORPAY_KEY"
                data-amount="20000"
                data-name="Recurring"
                data-description="Test Recurring payment"
                data-image="logo.png"
                data-prefill.name="User_Name"
                data-prefill.email="User Email"
                data-description="Total Payable Amount"
                data-order_id ="ORDER_ID"
                data-customer_id="CUSTOMER_ID"
                data-recurring ="1"
                data-theme.color="#55A410"></script>
```

I am able to charge payment through dashboard.
I want to create copy of previous order and deduct payment through token that was saved in first payment.

[image]

Comment: below code:
curl -u <YOUR_KEY_ID>:<YOUR_KEY_SECRET> \-X POST https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/create/recurring/ \-H "Content-Type: application/json" \-d '{  "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",  "contact": "9123456789",  "amount": 1000,  "currency": "INR",  "order_id": "order_1Aa00000000002",  "customer_id": "cust_1Aa00000000001",  "token": "token_1Aa00000000001",  "recurring": "1",  "description": "Creating recurring payment for Gaurav Kumar",  "notes": {    "note_key 1": "Beam me up Scotty",    "note_key 2": "Tea. Earl Gray. Hot."  }}'
error:Card not provided

Comment: https://razorpay.com/docs/api/recurring-payments/cards/subsequent-payments/#32-create-a-recurring-payment